# Use activate.ps1 script instead of activate.bat with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: windows, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to setup my developer environment in Windows (I know.. I know..). Cmder uses PowerShell and makes this quite a bit more comfortable. Virtualenv however still is a bit cumbersome, virtualenvwrapper supposedly makes it a bit more easier.

However, virtualenvwrapper is using the `activate.bat` in its `workon.bat` command, which has some problems with PowerShell. Since virtualenv supports Powershell out of the box since `1.7.1 (2012-02-16)` and offers its own `activate.ps1` script that works fine, I would like to use that instead.

The relevant part in `workon.bat`:

```
if not exist "%WORKON_HOME%\%VENV%\Scripts\activate.bat" (
    echo.
    echo.    %WORKON_HOME%\%VENV%
    echo.    doesn't contain a virtualenv ^(yet^).
    echo.    Create it with "mkvirtualenv %VENV%"
    goto END
)

call "%WORKON_HOME%\%VENV%\Scripts\activate.bat"
if defined WORKON_OLDTITLE (
    title %1 ^(VirtualEnv^)
)
```

Simply replacing `activate.bat` with `activate.ps1` doesn't work (opens a new shell or my editor depending on the set default program) and I've never did anything in batch, which is why I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you need is

```psh
& "$env:WORKON_HOME\$env:VENV\Scripts\activate.ps1"
```

assuming that `activate.ps1` is in the same folder as `activate.bat`. The other batch commands are just for displaying some help text if `activate.bat` doesn't exist, and for changing the window title. If you want the latter in PowerShell too, you can do it [like this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/30/powertip-change-the-powershell-console-title.aspx):

```psh
if ($env:WORKON_OLDTITLE) {
  $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $args[0] + ' (VirtualEnv)'
}
```